# Why Integer.respond_to?(:even?) returns false?

Tags: ruby

I've been going over the Ruby Koans and I've found the about_open_classes.rb koan interesting. Specially the last test where they modify `Integer#even?` method. I wanted to play around with this concept so I opened Irb and tried running `Integer.respond_to?(:even?)`, but to my surprise I got false. Then I tried `Fixnum.respond_to?(:even?)` and got false. I also tried `Integer.respond_to?(:respond_to?)` and got true and when I do `2.even?` I get true too. I have no idea what is going on. Can anyone tell what I'm missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An instance of Fixnum will `respond_to? :even?`, but the Fixnum *class itself* will not

```
>> 3.respond_to? :even?
=> true

>> 3.class
=> Fixnum

>> Fixnum.respond_to? :even?
=> false

>> Fixnum.class
=> Class
```

You can see how this works by defining your own test class:

```
class Test
  def self.a
    "a"
  end
  def b
    "b"
  end
end

>> Test.respond_to? :a
>> true
>> Test.respond_to? :b
>> false

>> t = Test.new
>> t.respond_to? :a
>> false
>> t.respond_to? :b
>> true
```

Comment: Since you beat me to a good answer, I added what I had for what's happening under the hood.